# PowerBI Matrix - Conditional Format by Row or Column

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

Instead of looking at the values in the whole matrix, is it possible to conditionally format by row or by column? i.e. for each hour, highlight across the days or for each day, highlight down across the hours. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make the formatting the same for each row or column, you could make a supportive measure and use that one for the formatting.

**Current:**

Formatting based on measure in the visual:

[image]

**Option 1: Rows the same**

Make a new measure, which calculates the total of the rows. ALL in calculates 'removes' the filter on Day, so you're getting the total for each hour, which you use for the formatting.

```
SUM ALL DAYS = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), ALL('Table'[Day]))
```

[image]

**Option 2: Columns the same**

Same principal, make a new measure which calculates the total for the columns.

```
SUM ALL HOUR = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), ALL('Table'[Hour]))
```

[image]

*Don't forget to choose the new measure as base for the fomatting!*

[image]

Comment: I would say this is the opposite of what he asked. I suppose he wanted to highlight the best / worst cells for each row, or the best/worst cells for each columns 
And this is what I was looking for as well haha